# jQuery .is(":hover") In IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-hover

I am having an issue checking the state of a div in IE8.  I want to check if the mouse is currently hovering over some divs or not. Currently in IE8, I get the following error:  `Syntax error, unrecognized expression: hover`.  Below is the jQuery that is causing the error:

```
// This function will close the slideout of widgets
function CloseWidgetPanel()
{
    if (!$("#widgets").is(":hover") && !$(".widgetPanel").is(":hover"))
    {
        if ($("#widgets").is(":animated"))
        {
            $("#widgets").stop(true, true);
        }
        $("#widgets").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 300);
    }
    else
    {
        // We are currently hovering over a panel, so check back in 2 seconds.
        setTimeout(CloseWidgetPanel, 2000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider storing the result of `$("#widgets")` as a variable instead of querying for it 4 times (this results in more DOM operations).

Comment: `:hover` is simply [not a valid jQuery selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: I think you need the `.hover()` event (a.k.a. `.on('hover', ...)`) instead.

Comment: Your title implies that this is only an IE8 issue, but with the invalid selector, it couldn't work anywhere.

Comment: @Sparky672 It should work in all browsers that implement queryselectorall and the :hover css selector, which is all modern browsers, not IE<9

Comment: @KevinB, thanks, that would explain it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Alternative way:

```
$(".widgetPanel, #widgets").hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('hover')
});
```

Then:

```
if (!$("#widgets").is(":hover") && !$(".widgetPanel").is(":hover"))

change to

if (!$("#widgets").hasClass('hover') && !$(".widgetPanel").hasClass('hover'))
```

Answer (score 7):

jQuery does not implement the `:hover` selector and IE8 doesn't support `queryselectorall`, therefore it fails. You'll have to find another way to detect that the element is currently being hovered over such as a mouseenter and leave event that sets a global (or parent scope) variable or applies a state class/attribute to the element.

Comment: or applies a class to the widget that signifies it is in a hover state

Comment: or initially set a null value on a variable, then give it a value within mouseeleave(), then reference it again in a conditional statement.  easy way to get around this IE8 issue.

Comment: IE8 Supports document.querySelectorAll http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff462057.aspx#selectorapi in standards mode